# AngularJS app with many files, stalled due max TCP requests

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome, tcp

I built an AngularJS app consisting of many js files. Chrome only allows for 6 TCP connections at the time so the other requests are stalled until the first 6 finish resulting in very long compound loading times.

How do I change the app so the TCP requests are not stalled by chrome and what is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Angular JS – but normally you should build (concatenate & minify) JS before delivering it on the web. Using single JS files is only useful during development or for apps that run locally.

Ergo: try to concatenate all modules into one file and load that in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, but I was using Visual Studio with Web API. My problem was the browser link plug-in for Visual Studio. It was hogging up the TCP connections in Chrome. By turning the browser link plug-in off, my http requests were not stalled anymore.